# The 'DisplayGroupTree' property cannot be set declaratively

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

In this code below i get an error saying "The 'DisplayGroupTree' property cannot be set declaratively."  This happened after i installed the SAP crystal report for visual studio 2015.

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrvDisplay" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" DisplayGroupTree="False"
        ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false" EnableParameterPrompt="false" />
```

If i remove DisplayGroupTree="False" then i dont get this error ...below attach screen shot

[![
Error
Missing parameter values.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XrW8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XrW8.png)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigureCrystalReports();
        }
        private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
        {



            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables;
            cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath(Session["Reportname"].ToString()));
            //DB Connection Start
            string Server1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
            string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Userid"];
            string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
            string DataBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBase"];
            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Server1;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = DataBase;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = user;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;

            ////Parameter setting Start
            ParameterDiscreteValue pmtDiscValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            pmtDiscValue1.Value = Session["LowerboundDate"];
            cryRpt.ParameterFields["LowerboundDate"].CurrentValues.Add(pmtDiscValue1);

            ParameterDiscreteValue pmtDiscValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            pmtDiscValue2.Value = Session["UpperboundDate"];
            cryRpt.ParameterFields["UpperboundDate"].CurrentValues.Add(pmtDiscValue2);

            ////Parameter setting End

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            CrvDisplay.SelectionFormula = Session["selectionformula"].ToString();
            CrvDisplay.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            CrvDisplay.RefreshReport();
        }
```

Comment: check this out if it can help you https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/999037

Answer (score 1):

as say @jambonick that command is obsolete

Just try to use

```
YOURReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
```